# No main manifest attribute in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, manifest.mf

I've successfully completed project and now create i need to create a jar file to submit it. I used Eclipse and MYSQL

In my `src` directory, I already created a folder `META-MF` with a `MANIFEST.MF` file that contains

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: FrameLogin
```

After compiling and save my program, I exported the jar file using the existing manifest `MANIFEST.MF` from my workspace and imported the jar file in the lib folder

When I finally run it on command prompt it gives me and error

> No main manifest attribute in jar

What am I missing here?

Additional question:  When creating a manifest it says

> It is important that the file ends with a blank line

What does it mean?

Comment: *what does this thing mean?* exactly what is written: you should have an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: About your main question, does `FrameLogin` belong to a package? Because in that case you should written the fully qualified name of the class, as in `com.mypackage.whatever.FrameLogin`.

Comment: does it count in the default package?,  how do i write  the fully qualified name of the class? could you explain me in details or send some reference ?

Comment: What do you mean "does it count in the default package"? About the fully qualified name, see my previous comment. The fully qualified name is the name of the package where the main class resides, then a dot, then the class name.

Comment: what I mean is  that, my class is in the default package

Comment: Does that class have a `public static void main(String args[])` method?

Comment: yes it has, what should i do then? Do I just put the class name ,how?

Comment: Everything you wrote thus far points to the fact that all of this should work as it is. Last thing you can do is to check the content of the JAR itself and see if it contains the class and the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Manifest specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest_Specification) a **newline** (`CR LF`, `LF` or `CR`) is **missing** at the end of your `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Because of the missing newline, the last line containing the `Main-Class` attribute is ignored:

> No main manifest attribute in jar

Or with other words,

> It is important that the file ends with a blank line